# How to format FCM json for background notifications iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling to find references that discuss how exactly to structure my message `.json`s for background-notifications in FCM. I have tried various configurations, but right now I have this:

```
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: "Title",
    },
    apns: {
        payload: {
            aps: {
                'contentAvailable': 1
            }
        },
    },
    token: registrationToken,
};
```

I want this message to show up as a notification--i.e. for the user to see it--but I also want to trigger:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

}
```

So I can perform data updates if the app is in background mode. I am able to see this notification, but that function isn't triggered when the notification arrives--so no data refresh is possible. How can I format my FCM `.json` to enable this?

Comment: How did this get solved?

Comment: I don't remember finding an answer to this. I stopped this project a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, according to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1), the key `contentAvailable` that you are using should actually be `content-available`, so without fixing this, the `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` function wouldn't be triggered anyway.

Now, FCM have an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#interpreting_notification_message_payload) of how the `.json` file should look like, so for your data it should be something like this:

```json
const message = {
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
      "title" : "Title"
    },
    "badge" : 1,
    "content-available": 1
  },
  "token" : registrationToken
}
```

Now I guess you'd like to customize the notification a bit more (for example adding body, subtitle etc.), so you may find the full list of keys organized in tables in the article [Generating a Remote Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification).

Comment: This throws an error in FCM: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "aps" at 'message': Cannot find field."

Comment: What FCM version are you using? may you attach some more code?

Comment: I see now that with the FCM REST v1 (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) it does looks like what you've posted, so what happens if you just replace `contentAvailable` with `content-available` on the original object?

Comment: I'm using the FCM Admin SDK for Node.js. And even though apple's docs mention the `content-available` syntax, the Admin SDK docs explicitly mention the key as `contentAvailable.` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.aps

Comment: And I believe I tried with `content-available` with no luck

Comment: Can you post the object that you are receiving as client (iOS device)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241399/discussion-between-ido-and-john-sorensen).

Answer (score 0):

You got payload and headers, payload should contain content_available = 1(not contentAvailable, other than that you are fine) and headers should have "apns-push-type" =  "background" and "apns-priority" = "5"

```
public class ApnsConfig {
    @Key("headers")
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    @Key("payload")
    private final Map<String, Object> payload;
    @Key("fcm_options")
    private final ApnsFcmOptions fcmOptions;
}
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)

Comment: Didn't hear back, did you manage to solve it? need any help? :)